# Tesseract OCR Python Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, ocr, tesseract

I am trying to install `tesseract` but if i follow all the steps I still get an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\julian\Documents\Schikka\tesseract.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('images/test.jpg')))
  File "C:\Users\julian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 122, in image_to_string
    config=config)
  File "C:\Users\julian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 46, in run_tesseract
    proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "C:\Users\julian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\subprocess.py", line 676, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\julian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\subprocess.py", line 957, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2]  the system cannot find the file specified.
```

I have tried to install it on linux as well and I still get an error code.

I currently have python 3.6

this is the code I tried:

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('images/test.jpg')))
```

please help me.

Comment: The path of the file maybe incorrect as the **traceback** appeals. Please check the image path!!!

Comment: @Julian - Make sure your tesseract binary file is in the same folder as your py file, or in one of the system paths.

Comment: @Julian Any feedback on my Answer below?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you haven't installed `tesseract` and/or configured the paths incorrectly. You may try below steps.

1. Download and install `tesseract 4.0 alpha` for 64-bit windows from
   [here](http://digi.bib.uni-mannheim.de/tesseract/tesseract-ocr-setup-4.00.00dev.exe).
2. Add  `C:\Program Files\Tesseract 4.0.0` to Windows
   environment variable `PATH`.
3. Set Windows environment variable
   `TESSDATA_PREFIX` to `C:\Program Files\Tesseract 4.0.0\tessdata`.
4. Type `tesseract -v` in command prompt to verify if it works properly. Suppose the `tesseract version` information will return.

Take note that the paths above is an example. You need to set it as to your actual program installation path.

Then you may modify your `pytesseract command` as below to try again.

```
ocr = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang='eng', boxes=False, \
        config='--psm 10 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789')
```

Hope this help.